# ORDERBY Month(datetime) SQL

Tags: sql, max, average

Hello all I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and needed some help with a small query

Here is my table:

```
Orders
-----------------
OrderID  Date(datetime)  Quantity
```

I need to find the avg, max and min quantity of each month. and also display the YEAR and Month
Because of thee requirements I was going to take the aproach of grouping by Month and then getting avg max and min through this. Is it possible? here is what i have so far

```
    Select YEAR(Orders.Date), MONTH(Orders.Date)
    From Orders
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to group by month and year, you can do it like this:

```
select Year(Orders.Date) as 'Year',
       MONTH(Orders.Date) as 'Month',
       avg(Quantity) as 'Average',
       max(Quantity) as 'Max',
       min(Quantity) as 'Min'
from Orders
group by YEAR(Orders.Date), MONTH(Orders.Date)
```

Comment: @user965824 the YEAR is the first column of my select.

Comment: Thanks, guess I am blind today .

Comment: @user965824 if it's working you should accept this answer, and also all of the others.